# unable to select tabs though used setOnTabSelectedListener()

Tags: android, android-layout

I am new to android I am trying to implement sliding view using tab layout.
I have implemented the following sliding is working fine but unable to select the tab values

```
TabLayout tabLayout;
ViewPager viewPager;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_contacts);
    tabLayout = (TabLayout)findViewById(R.id.tablayout);
    viewPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
    viewPager.setAdapter(new CustomAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(),getApplicationContext()));
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add the listener,

```
 tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
 viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
```

Answer (score 0):

try to comment these lines:

```
tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
        //viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
        //viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
    }
});
```